# Animation for some layout in an inflated row in a listview

Tags: android, listview, animation

There is a listview with inflated rows. At each row, there is a button called `btn_to_show_actual` to show the hidden relativelayout `ll_hide_btn` (a layout containing several buttons) from outside the right of the screen into the screen (at the same Y location) of its parent row.

```
 X_in_screen = Constants.SCREEN_W * 1/2 ; 
 X_out_screen = Constants.SCREEN_W 
 Y_in_screen = Constants.SCREEN_H /2;
```

The above are checked with proper figures.

Codes are as follows:

### Layout for each inflated row in the listview:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_to_show_actual"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_to_show_actual_selector"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_hide_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_to_show_actual"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_to_show_actual"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_to_show_actual"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_to_show"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_delete"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_left_selector"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_to_hide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_delete"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_right_selector"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_amend"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_delete_selector"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_amend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_share"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_input_selector"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_share"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_share2_selector"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

### Code:

```
btn_to_show_actual.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Utilities.system_toast(Show_database.this, "btn to show actual pressed" + "\n" + "X-screen=" + Constants.SCREEN_W + "; X-in=" + X_in_screen + "; X-out= " + X_out_screen + "; Y=" + Y_in_screen);

                        //btn_to_show_actual.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        btn_to_show.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        translate_to_left =  new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, X_out_screen,                   // from X0
                                Animation.ABSOLUTE, X_in_screen,        // to X1
                                Animation.ABSOLUTE, Y_in_screen,        // from Y0
                                Animation.ABSOLUTE, Y_in_screen);       // to Y1
                        translate_to_left.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                        translate_to_left.setDuration(800);
                        translate_to_left.setFillAfter(true);
                        translate_to_left.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                            public void onAnimationStart(Animation a) {
                            }
                            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation a) {}
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation a)
                            {
                                btn_to_hide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                btn_to_show.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }
                        });

                        ll_hide_btn.startAnimation(translate_to_left);
                    }
                });

                btn_to_hide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        Utilities.system_toast(Show_database.this, "btn to hide pressed");

                        translate_to_right =  new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, X_in_screen,               // from X0
                                Animation.ABSOLUTE, X_out_screen,           // to X1
                                Animation.ABSOLUTE, Y_in_screen,            // from Y0
                                Animation.ABSOLUTE, Y_in_screen);           // to Y1
                        translate_to_right.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                        translate_to_right.setDuration(800);
                        translate_to_right.setFillAfter(true);
                        translate_to_right.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                            public void onAnimationStart(Animation a) {
                            }
                            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation a) {}
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation a)
                            {
                                btn_to_hide.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                btn_to_show.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                btn_to_show_actual.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        });

                        ll_hide_btn.startAnimation(translate_to_right);
                    }
                });
```

### Question:

After pressing the `btn_to_show_actual`, the `ll_hide_btn` cannot translate from outside the screen into screen. How can I make the `ll_hide_btn` show / go away and translate properly?

Comment: Don't translate the y position just use a valueAnimator and animate from offset to 0. 0 being the final position, offset being a value that will put the view offscreen maybe use viewWidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using Animator instead of Animation since it only change the visual representation of an object. So you might have problems with the buttons touch coordinates using Animation

Animators on the other hand change the physical properties of the objects. So if you move a View to a new location, the touch coordinates will be mapped at the new location.

To get the behavior you want you don't need to translate the Y axis, only the X axis. You can set the initial TranslationX of ll_hide_btn at X_out_screen position to set ll_hide_btn offscreen, then animate to 0 if you want to translate the buttons into the screen

Your implementation could be something like:

Set ll_hide_btn translationX at X_out_screen position:

```
ll_hide_btn.setTranslationX(X_out_screen)
```

OnClickListeners:

```
btn_to_show_actual.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btn_to_show.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        ll_hide_btn.animate()
                .translationX(0f)
                .setDuration(800)
                .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator())
                .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        btn_to_hide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btn_to_show.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                    }
                });
    }
});

btn_to_hide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        ll_hide_btn.animate()
                .translationX(X_out_screen.toFloat())
                .setDuration(800)
                .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator())
                .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        btn_to_hide.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        btn_to_show.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btn_to_show_actual.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                    }
                });
    }
});
```